# cocos2d-x 3 create label in not deprecated way

Tags: c++, label, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to create a label using Arial font. I try 2 way, but both are declared deprecated. What is the good way of creating labels?

```
Label::create("Hello World", "Arial", 32); //declared deprecated
LabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Arial", 32); //declared deprecated
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```
std::string str = "五十嵐信介あろほほほaaaaaaaaaaaa";
cocos2d::ui::Text* titleLable = cocos2d::ui::Text::create(str,"AmericanTypewriter",35);
titleLable->setColor(Color3B::WHITE);
titleLable->setTextHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::CENTER);
titleLable->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
titleLable->setPosition(Vec2(130, visibleSize.height - 50));
titleLable->setContentSize(Size(visibleSize.width - 200, 150));
this->addChild(titleLable);
```

Comment: instead of using Labels I should use ui::Text? Does it work with TTF fonts only? Does is support shadow, stroke and other effects?